# Meta query compare date

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, datetime, meta-query

I need to query the **date:- 2020-01-06** If this date ( 2020-01-06 ) exists in the **_from** field in the post meta table. 
**_form** field is in timestamp format like **1578304800**.

This is how I am trying to do.

```php
$theBookingTime  = strtotime( '2020-01-06' ); 
$events_query = new WP_Query(
                    array(
                        'post_type' => array('yith_booking', 'post'),
                        'meta_query' => array(
                                            array( 'key' => '_from',
                                                   'value' => date('c', $theBookingTime),
                                                   'compare' => '=',
                                                   'type' => 'DATETIME',
                                                  )
                                              )
                         ));
```

ADDING FOR INFO :_

And if we convert the time stamp **"1578304800"** to date it get **2020-01-06 10:00:00**

And i need to compare only the date with the given timestamp in table field ( _form )>
I need to find the 2020-01-06 ** Only the date part from the date and time in the table**>>
If this can be done with the custom mysql also?  please suggest.

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all the non-sql stuff for now, and instead focus on the query

Answer (score 0):

You're using `'value' => date('c', $theBookingTime),`

The *'c'* corresponds to the output format of your date. What you're looking for is `'value' => date('Y-m-d', $theBookingTime),` where *Y* will output the year in 4 digits, *m* will output the month and *d* - the day.